# AC-215 Controller card reader

Tags: delphi, cardreader

I have AC-215 Controller system with card reader mechanism. Is there any way to read/manage information from card reader (when there is contact with card) using Delphi?

Comment: You should consult the manufacturer and/or vendor of this device to see if they have any API, most likely a web interface, if any. Does the device have an IP? If so, does it have a web interface you can open in a browser?

Comment: Just briefly looking at the specs, your answer should be yes. It's based on a SQL Server database.